# If condition in Unix and Linux env

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am trying to run a same code which is working fine in Unix but not in Linux.
Sample code:
if [ "$1" -eq "" ]
then
        echo "No parameter passed! Please pass the number of rows to be queued."
        exit 1
fi
echo "Parameter is $1";

**On Linux environment**
When i run **sh /tmp/script.sh** it throws error 
**/tmp/script.sh: line 1: [: : integer expression expected
Parameter is**
When i run **sh /tmp/script.sh 100** it thows an error
**/tmp/script.sh: line 1: [: : integer expression expected
Parameter is 100**

**On unix environment**
When i run **sh /tmp/script.sh** it says No parameter passed! Please pass the number of rows to be queued.
When i run **sh /tmp/script.sh 100** it says Parameter is 100.
When i run **sh /tmp/script.sh ABCD** it says No parameter passed! Please pass the number of rows to be queued.

Can anyone explain me why is it behaving differently? I thought these kind of functionalities shouldn't depend of environment.

Comment: Type `man test`. Search for `-eq`.

Comment: I replaced if [ "$1" -eq "" ] with if [[ "$1" -eq "" ]] in Linux and it worked. I am still wondering how and why.

Comment: It looks like what you have found in the description of `-eq` is not identical to what I have found. I wonder what your version says.

Comment: 2.6.32-642.6.2.el6.x86_64  does it make any sense? ran **uname -r**

Answer (score 0):

`-eq` does *numeric* comparison. You want `=` (single equals sign) for string comparisons. Have a look at [arithmetic expressions](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression) for more information.

Comment: I am just confused that if [ "$1" -eq "" ] statement works on Unix but not on Linux. I checked the shell and its ksh on both env,